# how to generate insert script for postgresql from a oracle table which has blob value

Tags: postgresql

I have an Oracle table which has a BLOB column. I need to generate an insert script compatible with Postgres.

I tried the below logic in Java but it is not working:

```
String value = null;
switch ( dataType ) {
     case Types.BLOB:
        Blob blob = rs.getBlob(colName);
        if ( ( blob != null ) && ( !rs.wasNull() ) ) {
        int blobLength = (int) blob.length(); 
        byte[] blobAsBytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
        value = blobAsBytes.toString();                 
        break;
    }
return value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `byte[]` array to one of [the supported formats](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html#AEN5690) for `bytea` columns, e.g. `E'\\xDEADBEEF'::bytea`

Something like:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(blobAsBytes.length * 2 + 12);
result.append("E'\\\\x");
for (int i = 0; i < blobAsBytes.length; i++)
{
  int c = (blobAsBytes[i] < 0 ? 256 + blobAsBytes[i] : blobAsBytes[i]);
  String hexString = Integer.toHexString(value);
  if (c < 16) result.append('0');
  result.append(hexString);
}
result.append("'::bytea');
value = result.toString();
```

I am not entirely sure if the `::bytea` cast is needed, but it won't hurt.